# InvalidOperationException due to circular dependency in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am getting the following *InvalidOperationException* when I try to save an entity with a one-to-one relationship:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to save changes because a
>   circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved: 'ForeignKey:
>   DeviceLicenseSubscriptionPlan {'LicenseId'} -> DeviceLicense {'Id'}
>   Unique ToPrincipal: License, ForeignKey: DeviceLicense
>   {'SubscriptionPlanId'} -> DeviceLicenseSubscriptionPlan {'Id'}
>   ToPrincipal: SubscriptionPlan'.

Here is my modell:

```
public class DeviceLicense
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public int DeviceLimit { get; set; }
    public DeviceLicenseSubscriptionPlan SubscriptionPlan { get; set; } = new DeviceLicenseSubscriptionPlan();
}

public class DeviceLicenseSubscriptionPlan 
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? LicenseId { get; set; }
    public DeviceLicense License { get; set; }
}
```

Here the `OnModelCreating()`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var deviceLicense = modelBuilder.Entity<DeviceLicense>().ToTable("DeviceLicense");
    deviceLicense.HasKey(l => l.Id);
    deviceLicense.HasOne<DeviceLicenseSubscriptionPlan>()
        .WithOne(s => s.License)
        .HasForeignKey<DeviceLicenseSubscriptionPlan>(s => s.LicenseId)
        .HasConstraintName("LicenseId");
    deviceLicense.Property(l => l.DeviceLimit).HasColumnName("DeviceLimit");

    var deviceLicenseSubPlan = modelBuilder.Entity<DeviceLicenseSubscriptionPlan>().ToTable("DeviceLicenseSubscriptionPlan");
    deviceLicenseSubPlan.HasKey(s => s.Id);
    deviceLicenseSubPlan.Property(s => s.Id).HasColumnName("SubscriptionPlanId");


    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

I am using EF Core 2.0. I probably do something wrong within the ModelBuilder? Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
deviceLicense.HasOne<DeviceLicenseSubscriptionPlan>()
```

It basically tells EF that there is no navigation property to `DeviceLicenseSubscriptionPlan` in `DeviceLicense`. However there *is a navigation property*, so EF by convention maps it to a second relationship with FK in `DeviceLicense` pointing to `DeviceLicenseSubscriptionPlan`. Which of course with the combination of the desired FK in `DeviceLicenseSubscriptionPlan` creates a cycle.

Make sure fluent configuration uses the correct overloads which exactly represent the presence/absence of a navigation property in either side of the relationship. In this particular case, replace the above with

```
deviceLicense.HasOne(l => l.SubscriptionPlan)
```